# Como otimizar ficheiros html e css?

Tags: html, css, htaccess

A otimização não acusa a compactação dos ficheiros html e css. Depois de compacta-los no minifier html e minifier css e de colocar o seguinte código no `htaccess`(*ver abaixo*) continua a não acusar a compactação no leitor que uso, `woorank`, ou seja, o que me falta para que o leitor de seo acuse a compactação?

```
<IfModule deflate_module>
    # Enable compression for the following file types.
    AddOutputFilterByType            \
     DEFLATE                         \
      application/javascript         \
      text/css                       \
      text/html                      \
      text/javascript                \
      text/plain                     \
      text/xml
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Boas
Tens aqui um site onde tem ferramentas que te podem ajudar... http://richardstoolbox.com/ Mas para o teu caso aconselho-te a procurares por algo do tipo GZIP Compression

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Tem ferramentos muito úteis. Tenho o código do Gzip no htaccess, o servidor está correto e o teste dá como comprimido mas na velocidade de dispositivos continua o pedido para compactar css

Answer (score 1):

Uso este código em .htaccess pra guardar o cache e melhorar a performance:

```
#Força a utilizar Cache-Control e Expires header
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

FileETag None

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

 ExpiresActive on
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"

 # Html
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

 # Data
 ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"

 # Feed
 ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
 ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"

 # Favicon
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

 # Media: images, video, audio
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

 # HTC files
 ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"

 # Webfonts
 ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

 # CSS / JS
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType application/x-javascript  "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

#Força o IE a sempre carregar utilizando a última versão disponível
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|gif|png|jpeg|pdf|xml|oga|ogg|m4a|ogv|mp4|m4v|webm|svg|svgz|eot|ttf|otf|woff|ico|webp|appcache|manifest|htc|crx|oex|xpi|safariextz|vcf)$" >
    Header unset X-UA-Compatible
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom_xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-eruby
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip

BrowserMatch ^HMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Obrigado Fabricio pela dica